# NuGet how to make Package without "Bin" Folder

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I am trying to get rid of **Bin** Folder in NuGet Package but preserve the structure.

part of my nuspec file:

```
<file src = "**\*.dll"/>
```

My Current package produces:
project1\bin\*.dll
project2\bin\*.dll

Desired Result:
 
project1\*.dll
project2\*.dll

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `<file src="bin\*.dll" target=".\" />`